# When will Apache 2.4.2 be available in a ppa or normal pkg release?

Tags: ppa, apache2

So Apache 2.4.2 was released on April 17th, 2012. As of yet, it doesn't seem to be in any repositories yet. All I can find out by googling is suggestions of building from the GIT source.

I'd rather not do this, as it complicates configuration and maintenance.

Just curious if anyone knows when it will be available in the repositories, or if anyone knows of a ppa that publishes the latest apache versions.

Comment: Arrival times in the repositories for something such as Apache will be (at the earliest) in Quantal, and probably only after its updated in Debian.

Comment: I kinda of expected that, but it's disappointing that an LTS is outdated before it's even released. Two months into an "LTS" and it won't pass PCI compliance scans. Sweet...

Comment: I check at least once a week if the Debian or Ubuntu communities have any news about when I can expect Apache 2.4.x in the repositories, frustratingly there's still no news...

Comment: You may find this of worth, explaining why its not latest apache: [Why don't the Ubuntu Respositories have the latest versions of software](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Please see [this open issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/939300). It might get into 13.04.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a PPA that works for me on 12.10: https://launchpad.net/~derek-morton/+archive/apache-2.4

and for 13.04: https://launchpad.net/~rhardy/+archive/apache24x

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.10 (not released yet at the time of writing) recently added apache2.4 to its nightly builds.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/raringautomatedsuggestions/+bug/939300 
http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu