# mod_usertrack with X-Forwarded-For (proxy) IPs, apache 2.2

Tags: 11.10, apache2

I'm using apache 2.2 with [mod_usertrack](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_usertrack.html), behind a reverse proxy (load balancer).

Now, the proxy disguises the client's real IP addresses (keeps them in the X-Forwarded-For header), and forwards the request along.

mod_usertrack uses the clients' IP (along with some noise) to generate a GUID for each client. However, because of the proxy, it only sees a single IP and the generated GUIDs for each client are very similar (even with some possible collisions).

I would like to upgrade apache to version 2.4, but it seems to be [somewhat of a project](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153153/apache-2-4-2-ppa-or-normal-pkg-release-date/229971#229971). I did manage to compile it using [this post](http://devincharge.com/compiling-apache-2-4-ubuntu-12-04/) and a few others, only to discover the folder structure does not resemble the one I had before (default ubuntu). I'm weary of tweaking it myself ... and I will be making my life miserable if I want to upgrade the server later on.

So ... what are my options?

1. Is there a good unofficial repository that packages apache 2.4 for Oneiric? (please provide a short 'how to', I'm not great in installing packages)
2. Is there an alternative route to solve this? (Upgrading just the user_track module? Another module that works with apache 2.2?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so here are my insights after a few more hours of looking into it:

1. Using a custom-built apache is definitely not recommended in a production environment (unless you really know what you're doing ... and I certainly don't fall into that category)
2. It seems you can simply copy-paste modules from apache 2.4 to apache 2.2, and there's a chance it will work (for a simple module like usertrack, it seems to just work).
3. **The usertrack module from apache 2.4 does't even support X-Forwarded-For** ! Not sure why I thought it will.
4. Instead, I just grabbed [mod_cookietrack](https://github.com/jib/mod_cookietrack/) - a 3rd party custom module. Installation is dead simple, and it just does the job! (it's compatible with apache 2.2)

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. `mod_cookietrack` worked very well for me too.